# Generic Stack assistance

Tags: java

I am having a really hard time with the below code... I am trying to get apple, orange, and banana to show up as the push, pull, and peek.  However, I keep getting 0's

```
   import java.util.*;

   public class GenericStackApp {

       private static int apple;
       private static int banana;
       private static int orange;

       static void showpush(Stack st, int apple) 
       {
            st.push(new Integer(apple + banana + orange));
            System.out.println("push(" + apple + banana + orange + ")");
            System.out.println("stack: " + apple + banana + orange );
       }

       static void showpop(Stack st) 
       {
            System.out.print("pop -> ");
            Integer a = (Integer) st.pop();
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println("stack: " + st);
       }

       public static void main(String args[]) 
       {
           Stack st = new Stack();
           System.out.println("stack: " + st);
           showpush(st, apple);
           showpush(st, banana);
           showpush(st, orange);
           showpop(st);
           showpop(st);
           showpop(st);
           try 
           {
               showpop(st);
           } catch (EmptyStackException e) 
           {
               System.out.println("3 items in the stack");
           }
        }
    }
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: for first, try to indent and format your code properly.

Comment: All ints get initialized to `0` if you don't provide an initial value.  If you never assign a value to an int variable, it will never change and will always be `0`.

Comment: On a different note: You may want to rename your `apple` parameter to `showPush` to, e.g., `fruit` for clarity, and so it doesn't conflict with the field named `apple` (which is not a problem in itself, but is one more thing that can contribute to your confusion). Your intentions of `showPush` are unclear, why are you adding the three integers `apple`, `banana`, and `orange` together?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the variables apple, banana and orange like this:

```
     private static int apple = 1;
     private static int banana = 2;
     private static int orange = 3;
```